# css styling of division within division in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

I have a css sub-level question. normally people seem to define a style for a specific class. This is what I started out with:

```
.divholder {
  width:750px;
  border:none
  font-size:12;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }

 .five {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float:left;
  }
```

This worked fine to make a division with five subdivisions within that larger one. it currently holds buttons in an online form with five options, so hence the five.
Now Im trying to specify the division in my css file, so that I do not constantly have to define the div class="..." in the html part. This looks as follows:

```
form.cmxform div {
  width:750px;
  border:none;
  font-size:12;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  }

form.cmxform div div {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float:left;
         }
```

The specs are simply copied from the classes, which work well in chrome and IE.
Oddly enough, when I apply the above sub-specifications, it works in IE, but not in Chrome. Chrome puts every division on a seperate line with the lower code, but not with the top code. Does anybody have an idea why this would be the case, and how I could solve it?
thanks for any advice or remarks you might have!

*edit
the html code this applies to is the following:

```
<li><label>&nbsp;</label><div><div class="five">Zeker Niet</div><div class="five">&nbsp;</div><div class="five">&nbsp;</div><div class="five">&nbsp;</div><div class="five">Zeker Wel</div></div></li>
     <li><label>&nbsp;</label><div><div>--</div><div>-</div><div>0</div><div>+</div><div>++</div></div></li>
```

The top-line in which the div class is specifiek works well in both chrome and IE9, but the line below it only works in IE9, not chrome

Comment: Please post the HTML this applies to and if possible, a jsFiddle example.

Comment: It would also help greatly to identify which version of IE you are using, as your CSS code contains some HTML5 elements, that the older versions of IE do not support.

Comment: sorry, I added part of the html text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated]**

With your syntax, `form.cmxform div`'s css will affect your more nested `divs`.

To access a specific level of child element on the hierarchy, use `form.cmxform > div` and `form.cmxform > div > div` with `>` accessing the direct descendent.

In your example, you need to write :

```
form.cmxform li > div {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 750px;
}

form.cmxform li > div > div {
  text-align:center;      /* added for style */
  width:100px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: @ Bigood:  This seems to have only effected the display in IE9, which went from correctly displaying this, to putting the divisions on seperate lines, but I did not effect the chrome display. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've looked at the fiddle example, which looks great. So then I've copy/pasted your exact syntax into my css and php file, and it doesn't show up correctly in either IE or chrome. Where the div class is specified, it shows up correctly, but if It's not specified, each div is on a seperate line. I really don't know what I could be doing wrong if simply copy/pasting something that seems to work, doesn't work :S

Comment: @Jeroen Please provide more HTML or a link to your website, or create your JSFiddle with the maximum of code possible to get the closest of your local website ; your HTML seems a bit messy to me.

Comment: @ Bigood: here is a link to the webpage http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/verwerking.php
It's about the second page on that one (they are nested in cases)

Comment: @Jeroen See my updated answer. If you had provided your website / more  code at the first place, it would have been faster :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked! *excited* :P Sorry for not posting the full code earlier, but I thought it would be a hassle to go through more code than necessary, but I can see now that I didn't post all the relevant code in the first place ;)